# Can I use my own image as a React Loading icon/img

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We all know what a loading icon is, in React, I am wanting to replace that icon with an image/gif I have created. I have used `npm i react-loading` as the package, however, as this is my first time with this package, I am unsuccessful in having my images display at all. Im not entirely sure if this is due to a pathing error, or something else.

The intentions of this loader was to display this gif while the DOM is rendering, however, since I created the gifs myself, I love them so much I want to force other people to watch the gif in it's entirety before continuing. I have set a 5 second timeout on it, but not exactly sure if that was the right move. Maybe having a ternary would have been a simpler way to accomplish this.

Below is the Loading component I have set:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Loading from 'react-loading'

const loadingGifsList = [
    '../loading-images/l1.gif',
    '../loading-images/l2.gif',
    '../loading-images/l3.gif',
    '../loading-images/l4.gif',
    '../loading-images/l5.gif',
    '../loading-images/l6.gif',
    '../loading-images/l7.gif',
    '../loading-images/l8.gif',
    '../loading-images/l9.gif',
    '../loading-images/l10.gif',
    '../loading-images/l11.gif',
    '../loading-images/l12.gif',
    '../loading-images/l13.gif'
]

const LoadingPage = () => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
    const loadingGif = loadingGifsList[Math.floor(Math.random() * loadingGifsList.length)]

    useEffect(() => {
        const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            setIsLoading(false)
        }, 5000);
        
        return () => clearTimeout(timeout)
    }, [])
    
    if (isLoading) {
        return (
            <>
                <div>
                    <Loading src={loadingGif} />
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default LoadingPage
```

I have an array of gifs, and one will be randomly selected.

Below is my `App.js`:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Header from './components/Header.js'
import Add from './components/Add.js'
import Rules from './components/Rules.js'
import Select from './components/SelectGame'
import Player from './components/PlayerSelect.js'
import Board1 from './components/Player1_Board'
import Board2 from './components/Player2_Board'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
// import LoadingPage from './components/Loading.js'

// import css
import IndexCSS from './index.module.css';
import LoadingPage from './components/Loading.js'

const App = () => {
  // API data
  let [games, setGames] = useState([])
  // show/hides Add.js
  let [showAdd, setAdd] = useState(false)
  // show/hides Rules.js
  let [showRules, setRules] = useState(true)
  // show/hides SelectGame.js
  let [showSelect, setSelect] = useState(false)
    // show/hides the PlayerSelect and Player1/Player2 board until choice is made on SelectGame.js
  let [currentGameID, setCurrentGameID] = useState('')
    // show/hides PlayerSelect.js page
  let [playerSelect, setPlayerSelect] = useState(true)
    // show/hides Player1_Board.js page
  let [showP1, setP1] = useState(false)
  // show/hides Player2_Board.js page
  let [showP2, setP2] = useState(false)
  //show/hides loading images
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)

  //=========================================================================
  //DELETE GAME
  const handleDelete = (event) => {
    axios.delete('https://connect4back.herokuapp.com/api/connect4/' + event.id).then((response) => {
      getGames();
    })
  }

  //=========================================================================
  //EDIT GAME
  const handleUpdate = (game) => {
    axios.put('https://connect4back.herokuapp.com/api/connect4/' + game.id, game).then((response) => {
      getGames();
    })
  }

  //=========================================================================
  //Create new game with players
  const handleCreate = (add) => {
    axios.post('https://connect4back.herokuapp.com/api/connect4', add).then((response) => {
      getGames();
    })
  }
  //=========================================================================
  //collect from database
  const getGames = () => {
    axios.get('https://connect4back.herokuapp.com/api/connect4').then((response) =>
      setGames(response.data),
      // , (err) => 
      // console.log(err)
    )
  }
  //=========================================================================
  //useEffect to collect from database
  useEffect(() => {
    getGames();
  }, [])

  // ========================================================================
  // display page
  return (
    <>
    <div>
      <LoadingPage isLoading={isLoading} setIsLoading={setIsLoading} />
    </div>
    

    
    <div className={IndexCSS.appContainer}>
      {/* Header of app */}
      <Header setAdd={setAdd} setRules={setRules} setSelect={setSelect} setCurrentGameID={setCurrentGameID} setP1={setP1} setP2={setP2}/>
      <div key={games.id}>
        {/* Show/Hide Rules.js */}
        {
          showRules === true ? <Rules setRules={setRules}/> : null
        }
        {/* Show/Hide Add.js */}
        {
          showAdd === true ? <Add handleCreate={handleCreate} setAdd={setAdd} setSelect={setSelect}/> : null
        }
        {/* show/hide SelectGame.js */}
        {
          showSelect === true ? <Select games={games} setSelect={setSelect} setCurrentGameID={setCurrentGameID} setPlayerSelect={setPlayerSelect}/> : null
        }
        {

        }
        {/* render game based on game ID selected from SelectGame.js */}
        {games.map((game) => {
          if (game.id === currentGameID) {
            return (
              <div key={game.id}>
                {/* Have player select P1 or P2, then render page */}
                {
                  playerSelect === true ? <Player game={game} setP1={setP1} setP2={setP2} setSelect={setSelect} setPlayerSelect={setPlayerSelect}/>: null
                }
                {/* show P1 page if true, else null */}
                {
                  showP1 === true? <Board1 game1={game} handleDelete={handleDelete} handleUpdate={handleUpdate} /> : null
                }
                {/* show P1 page if true, else null */}
                {
                  showP2 === true? <Board2 game2={game} handleDelete={handleDelete} handleUpdate={handleUpdate} /> : null
                }
              </div>
            )
          } else {
            return null
          }
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

**What is this currently producing?**

So currently, when the page is loading, I have four circles moving left to right, and the most right circle fades out as a "new" circle (far left) fades in. It looks like a loading icon if you ask me. Why is it in the top left corner and not the centre? I have no idea.

**Summary**

In react, I want to use my gif/img as my loading "icon." I also like this image to be the centre of the screen. Just like most loaders, I would also like this to be the only thing visible while the loading icon is showing, and when it ends, display what the DOM has rendered.

Below is an image of what I see in the top left corner of my screen: [image: 4 dots in the top left corner]

Comment: *We all know what a loading icon is, in React* - no, what is a loading icon?

Comment: @Konrad You can find several examples of different loading icons here: [Examples](https://www.davidhu.io/react-spinners/)

Comment: You said that you want to *replace that icon* so it sounds like there is a default loading animation, but I haven't every seen it

Comment: That is what I was thinking as well, maybe it is a default animation. I have added a photo to this post so you can see what it looks like, maybe that will provide clarity

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but couldn't you just do `<img src={loadingGif} alt="loading spinner" />`? And drop the whole react-loading dependency.

Comment: make sure your images are in the public folder

Comment: If you would like to show only loading icon, in your app.js you should have condition to render only `LoadPage` component when `isLoading===true`, otherwise render page components only. To be able to make loading icon in the middle of the page you should write some css

Comment: @3limin4t0r This is my first time trying something like this, so Im not sure, but it is worth a try. Are you saying to add that syntax inside of the loadingGifsList?

Comment: @Sedat Polat the only thing that confuses me about that is how to change the status of the current loading icon. Other than using npm I react-loading , I have not used anything else. So I'm not aware of any className or ID to even attempt to alter it.

Comment: Here is a simple example https://codesandbox.io/s/long-paper-2gbv1b?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Not sure how to change loading icon in the library you are using, you can create your own loading component, if it does not support the icon you are looking for.

Comment: @Sedat Polat I got it to work! I don't think I could have done with without that sandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment section, you should move `Loading` component condition in your parent component. Here is the [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-paper-2gbv1b) code reference. Also I am sharing code below.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Loading = () => {
  return <span>loading...</span>;
};

export default function App() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }, 2000);
  });

  return (
    <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
      {isLoading && <Loading />}
      {!isLoading && (
        <div>
          <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `isLoading` state outside of the loading component and instead into the App.js component. Then, you should conditionally render only the loading component when the app is loading (basically the code you have in your loading component right now, that should be moved to `App.js`). You should then change your loading component to always render the GIF (since its render is controlled by App.js)

Answer (score 0):

Is this the library that you are using? https://github.com/fakiolinho/react-loading/blob/master/lib/react-loading.jsx#L7

As far as I checked, the library does not support any custom loading image.

I would recommend you use the official React Suspense instead and of course you can do any custom loading image.
https://17.reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html